# Using the SSM send_command in Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-ssm

I'm trying to create a lambda function that will shutdown systemd services running on an EC2 instance. I think using the ssm client from the boto3 module probably is the best choice, and the specific command I was considering to use is the send_command(). Ideally I would like to use Ansible to shutdown the systemd service. So I'm trying to use the "AWS-ApplyAnsiblePlaybooks" It's here that I get stuck, it seems like the boto3 ssm client wants some parameters, I've tried following the boto3 documentation [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.send_command), but really isn't clear on how it wants me to present the parameters, I found the parameters it's looking for inside the "AWS-ApplyAnsiblePlaybooks" document - but when I include them in my code, it tells me that the parameters are invalid. I also tried going to AWS' GitHub repository because I know they sometime have [examples of code](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/python/example_code/ssm) but they didn't have anything for the send_command(). I've upload a [gist](https://gist.github.com/reubendevries-cta/9b1c4c303112c20cf6394201487f349f) in case people are interested in what I've written so far, I would definitely be interested in understanding how others have gotten their Ansible playbooks to run using ssm via boto3 python scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I can see by looking at the [documentation for that SSM document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-state-manager-ansible.html) and the code you shared in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/reubendevries-cta/9b1c4c303112c20cf6394201487f349f). you need to add `"SourceType":["S3"]` and you need to have a path in the `Source Info` like:

```
{
   "path":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/path_to_directory_or_playbook_to_download"
}
```

so you need to adjust your global variable S3_DEVOPS_ANSIBLE_PLAYBOOKS.

Take a look at the CLI example from the doc link, it should give you ideas on how yo re-structure your Parameters:

```
aws ssm create-association --name "AWS-ApplyAnsiblePlaybooks" \
--targets Key=tag:TagKey,Values=TagValue \
--parameters '{"SourceType":["S3"],"SourceInfo":["{\"path\":\"https://s3.amazonaws.com/path_to_Zip_file,_directory,_or_playbook_to_download\"}"],"InstallDependencies":["True_or_False"],"PlaybookFile":["file_name.yml"],"ExtraVariables":["key/value_pairs_separated_by_a_space"],"Check":["True_or_False"],"Verbose":["-v,-vv,-vvv, or -vvvv"]}' \
--association-name "name" --schedule-expression "cron_or_rate_expression"
```